# Sieve of Eratosthenes wrong output

Tags: c, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I was trying to find out the sum of all prime up to 2 million.

**So I wrote the following code for it:**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define limit 2000000
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int *sieve, i, j;
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;
    sieve = malloc(sizeof(int)*limit);
    for(i=2;i<=limit;i++)
        sieve[i] = 1;
    for(i=2;i<=limit;i++)
    {
        if(sieve[i])
        {
            for(j=i;j*i<=limit;j++)
                sieve[j*i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(i=2;i<=limit;i++)
{
        if(sieve[i])
            sum += i;
    }
    printf("The sum is %llu\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The answer should be `142913828922`, but I am getting `142889228620`.

Can you tell me what is going wrong? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int *sieve, i, j;
for(j=i;j*i<=limit;j++)
```

The calculation `j*i` overflows for `i > 65535`. In this case, that spuriously produces some pseudo-composites.

Stop sieving when `i` reaches the square root of the limit.

Comment: Thank you, that clarified my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

I think, you incorrectly malloc memory for sieve.
Try:

```
sieve = malloc(sizeof(int)*limit + 1);
```

Comment: Good spot. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to the sum in the first loop, and avoid multiplying i*j which might overflow. *Also allocate space for limit+1 items*.

```
for(i=2;i<=limit;i++)
{
    if(sieve[i])
    {
        // Add to sum
        sum += i;
        // Zero all multiples of i, up to limit
        for(j=i; j <= limit; j+=i)
            sieve[j] = 0;
    }
}
printf("The sum is %llu\n",sum);
```

The code above gives me the result you wanted.